# How to establish the type of a class type in Java, without instantiated objects?

Tags: java, class

Suppose I have an array of class values in Java and I want to iterate through the array to find at which position is located a Double.
I tried the following:

```
public class ClassTypes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class []types = {String.class, Double.class};
        for (int i = 0 ; i < types.length; i++)
        {
                if (types[i].isInstance(Double.class)){
                    System.out.println("DOUBLE"); //never printed 
                }
        }
    }}
```

I have no instance of an object so I can't use instanceof, and I would like to avoid the use of getName on class object to perform the comparison.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: The method `isInstance` takes an `Object` as argument, not an actual instance of `Class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`types[i].equals(Double.class)`?

Comment: Actually, the `==` instead of `equals()` is also valid here.

Comment: yeah classes are == by definition but both == and equals **DO NOT** reflect `isInstanceOf`, the answer is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is [`Double.class.isAssignableFrom(types[i])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29), not `equals` and not == (they are the same for Class). For final classes like Double and String it doesn't matter of course.

If you have tried to check if the class is a `java.lang.Number` (or any interface/abstract class), the *==* approach  would have failed.